# Callback method in RIA Services in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight 4 appliction. This appliation is using RIA Services for operations. I have an operation that I want to do something when it has completed. I know that I need to wireup a callback, but I'm not sure how. Currently, I have the following:

```
DomainContext.CalculateTotal(param1, param2, OnCalculateTotalCompleted);

...

private void OnCalculateTotalCompleted(InvokeOperation response)
{
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error that says:
*No overload for method 'CalculateTotal' takes 3 arguments.*

What am I doing wrong? How do I wireup a callback for this specific operation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's another parameter that you have to add at the end (`UserState`), just use "null".

```
DomainContext.CalculateTotal(param1, param2, OnCalculateTotalCompleted, null);
```

Comment: Thanks! I always thought the user state was optional.

Answer (score 1):

The DomainContext.CalculateTotal needs a 4th argument "Object state", so give it a `null`, and you are OK.